# Jasper report - how to pass date parameter as "day", "month", "year" part from java to jasper report using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, jasper-reports

I want to pass "month", "year" parameters from java to jasper report using SQL. I have already hard coded the day value. I just want to join the day, month and year parameter as a date string, but I am getting error

> java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843: not a valid month

Below is my code:

```
WHERE TO_DATE(START_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS')>=  ADD_MONTHS( TO_DATE('26-' || UPPER($P{MONTH}) || '-' ||  $P{YEAR} ,'DD-MM-YYYY') ,-1)
AND 
TO_DATE(END_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS') <=  ADD_MONTHS( TO_DATE('26-' || UPPER($P{MONTH})|| '-' ||  $P{YEAR} ,'DD-MM-YYYY') ,0)
```

Comment: `DATE_ADD ( NOW ( ) , INTERVAL 1 MONTH )` ? try this

Comment: I want to know whether this parameter concatenation is correct or not. **"TO_DATE('26-' || UPPER($P{MONTH}) || '-' ||  $P{YEAR} ,'DD-MM-YYYY')"**

Comment: You should tag `oracle` also. Concatenation looks fine, although `UPPER` is useless. Are you passing a two digits month (with leading zero) string?

Comment: Iam passing month like this "Jun". Three letter month word

Comment: I would suggest you to copy your SQL and paste it in the text field so that you can check SQL and verify date format.

Comment: I have tried this format. "DD-MMM-YYYY". But it throws error too. **ORA-01821: date format not recognized**

Answer (score 0):

Use following format: `DD-MMM-YYYY`.